# Find the smallest natural number $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems, decimal-expansion

Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that rightmost digit is $6$ and when we deleted that digit $6$ and add it to the left of the number we get $4n$.

Example of the operation:

$123456$ becomes $612345$

$16$ becomes $61$

$66$ becomes $66$

Comment: So the natural number $n$ is given by a decimal expansion $dd\dots d6$ (with $d$ not necessarily all equal), and when we strip the digit $6$ and prepend it to the rest of digits, then $6dd\dots d$ appears equal $4n$ – and you need to find the smallest $n$ that has this property. Is this formulation correct?

Comment: Yeah, I got that now CiaPan, I think that's what it is.

Comment: yes, I think it's wrong, because I meant the single-digit of the number $n$ wrote in the decimal.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean? The last comment did not really help.

Comment: I think you don't mean "add it to the left of the number". I think you mean "append it to the left of the remaining number."

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ ends with 6, then $4n$ ends with 4 (because $6\cdot 4 = 24$). So the tail looks like

```
.....6 * 4 = .....4
```

Then we know $n$ ends with 46 – and so on:

```
....46 * 4 = ....84
...846 * 4 = ...384
..3846 * 4 = ..5384
.53846 * 4 = .15384
153846 * 4 = 615384
```

Done.

An example of a larger number with the same property is 153846153846153846.

Answer (score 0):

Just start playing around with some numbers. So far, we know that:

```
...FEDCBA6
       x 4
----------
6...FEDCBA
```

where we can find each digit `A, B, C, ...` one by one until we reach a `6`. Time to do some elementary school arithmetic: `6 * 4 = 24`, so `A` is `4` and we can carry the `2`:

```
        2
...FEDCB46
       x 4
----------
6...FEDCB4
```

Likewise, `4 * 4 + 2 = 18`, so `B = 8` and we carry the `1`:

```
       12
...FEDC846
       x 4
----------
6...FEDC84
```

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

$n = 10x + 6$ where $10^{d-1} \le x \le 10^d - 1$.

$4n = 6 \cdot 10^d + x$

$40x + 24 = 6 \cdot 10^d + x$

$39x + 24 = 6 \cdot 10^d$

$13x + 8 = 2 \cdot 10^d$

$2\cdot 10^d \equiv 8 \pmod{13}$

$10^d \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$

```
 Multiples of 13: 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91, 104, 117
```

\begin{align}
   10^2 &\equiv 100 \equiv 9 \pmod{13}\\
   10^3 &\equiv 90  \equiv -1 \pmod{13}\\
   10^4 &\equiv -10 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}\\
   10^5 &\equiv 30  \equiv 4 \pmod{13}
\end{align}

The smallest such $d$ is $d=5$.

$13x + 8 = 200000 \implies x = 15384$

So $n = 153846$

### Alternate solution

$2 \cdot 10^d = 13x + 8$

$10^d \cdot \dfrac{2}{13} = x + \dfrac{8}{13}$

Note $\dfrac{2}{13} = 0. \overline{153846}$ and 
$\dfrac{8}{13} = 0. \overline{615384}$

So

$10^5 \cdot \dfrac{2}{13} = 15384 + \dfrac{8}{13}$

So $n = 153846$